# Going through 2 lists with array data

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

This one is causing me a headache, and I am having trouble to find a solution with a for-loop.

Basically, my data looks like this:

```
short_list = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12] ]
long_list  = [ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13] ]
```

I would need to know how many times each number from each row in the short_list appears in each row of the long_list, and the comparison is NOT needed when both list indices are the same, because they come from the same data set.

Example: I need to know the occurrence of each number in [1, 2, 3] in the long_list rows [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10] and [9, 10, 11, 12, 13].
And then continue with the next data row in short_list, etc.

Comment: I cannot understand this part, *the comparison is NOT needed when both list indices are the same, because they come from the same data set.*
Provide an example which shows this case.

Comment: With that I mean that we know already that the row [1, 2, 3] from the short_list, appears in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. I do not need to compare those numbers, since they are a match. And that is valid for every index of the rows. I only need to compare indices that are not equal for both.

Comment: What's the correct answer for the given example?

Comment: @ElFred: what is the desired output?

Comment: [ [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0] ], when scanning the short list from left to right.

Comment: @ElFred, did one of the below answers help? if so, feel free to accept one (tick on left) so other users can see an accepted solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I selected the most comprehensible one for myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for L1 in short_list:
  for L2 in long_list:
    if not set(L1).issubset(set(L2)):
      for x in L1:
        print("{} has {} occurrences in {}".format(x, L2.count(x), L2))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I actually selected this as my preferred solution, because it was easily understandable, and it was short. Other given solutions were valid as well, but this one wins points due to simplicity. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it. It's straight off the top of my head, so there is probably a much better way to do it.

```
from collections import defaultdict

short_list = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12] ]
long_list  = [ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13] ]

occurrences = defaultdict(int)

for i, sl in enumerate(short_list):
    for j, ll in enumerate(long_list):
        if i != j:
            for n in sl:
                occurrences[n] += ll.count(n)

>>> occurrences
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 1, 10: 1, 11: 0, 12: 0})
```

Note that `enumerate()` is used to provide indices while iterating. The indices are compared to ensure that sub-lists at the same relative position are not compared.

The result is a dictionary keyed by items from the short list with the values being the total count of that item in the long list sans the sublist with the same index.

Comment: This gives the expected result!

Answer (score 2):

This is a brute-force solution. I've amended the input data to make the results more interesting:

```
from collections import Counter
from toolz import concat

short_list = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12] ]
long_list  = [ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [2, 3, 11, 12, 13] ]

for idx, i in enumerate(short_list):
    long_list_filtered = (x for x in concat(long_list[:idx] + long_list[idx+1:]) if x in set(i)))
    print(idx, Counter(long_list_filtered))

# 0 Counter({2: 2, 3: 2})
# 1 Counter({4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1})
# 2 Counter()
# 3 Counter({10: 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

**Possible Approach**:

- Loop over each list in `short_list`.
- Flatten every list in `long_list` that is not the same index as the current list, and convert it to a set.
- Create a [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to store the counts for each element in short list that appears in the flattened list.

**Demo:**

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

short_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
long_list  = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13]]

for i, short_lst in enumerate(short_list):
    to_check = set(chain.from_iterable(long_list[:i] + long_list[i+1:]))
    print(Counter(x for x in short_lst if x in to_check))
```

**Output:**

```
Counter({2: 1, 3: 1})
Counter({4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1})
Counter({9: 1})
Counter({10: 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
short_list = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12] ]
long_list  = [ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13] ]
occ = []
for si in short_list:
    occi = []
    for i, e in enumerate(si):
        count = 0
        for li in long_list:
            for j, e1 in enumerate(li):
                if i == j:
                    continue
                elif e == e1:
                    count += 1
        occi.append(count)
    occ.append(occi)
print occ
```

This should work,
Happy coding :)

Comment: It doesn't give the expected outcome. The result is only correct for the first row. This should be the expected outcome: [ [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0] ]